# Select a word from a line in a list and print the line with the word uppercase

Tags: python-3.x

I want to make a for loop that searches for a specific word and prints the line with that word but the word is in uppercase.

```
for i in quotes:

   if 'love' in i:
       print(i)
       if 'power' in i:
           i.replace('power','POWER')
           print(i)
       if 'power' and 'love' in i:
           print(i.upper())
```

Comment: can you provide details about input, your input is string or file?

Comment: 1) `if 'power' and 'love' in i:` doesnt do what you think it does (it will ALWAYS be True). 2) the second `if` should go before the first. Lastly use `.tolower()`.

Answer (score -1):

```
print(instr.replace(word, word.upper()))
```